# Minimum and maximum values for MKCoordinateSpan

Tags: ios, mapkit

I would like to validate, maybe get a little mathematical context from someone smarter than me, that the minimum and maximum values for `MKCoordinateSpan` are 0 and 180?

Here is the [`MKCoordinateSpan` documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcoordinatespan)

It seems like every integer value (1,2,3) represents one degree of latitude or longitude. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. `MKCoordinateSpan.latitudeDelta` or `longitudeDelta` represents one degree of latitude or longitude. One degree is always approximately 111 kilometers (69 miles).

I tried to zoom in/out the MKMapView to check the minimum and maximum values.

```
MAX ZOOM:
MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 135.68020269231502, longitudeDelta: 131.8359359933973)

MIN ZOOM:
MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.00033266201122472694, longitudeDelta: 0.00059856596270435602)
```